# How does weka handle overfitting in the information gain calculation?

Tags: weka, information-theory

I was just messing around with the Information Gain Attribute Evaluator of WEKA when I stumbled over some inconsistency when handling overfitting attributes. In my relation I use 3 numeric attributes and a class attribute which divides between failing and correct data sets. This class attribute only depends on attr3 while the other two attributes just have random values. So this is the ARFF file:

```
@relation TEST

@attribute attr1 numeric
@attribute attr2 numeric
@attribute attr3 numeric
@attribute class {failing,correct}

@data
1,      12.714813, 5000, failing
26,     -10000,    0,    correct
10,     9.547521,  5000, failing
-10000, 3.699694,  0,    correct
38,     6.1541,    5000, failing
```

After I executed the Information Gain Attribute Evaluator with the default settings, this is the output ranking:

```
=== Attribute Selection on all input data ===

Search Method:
    Attribute ranking.

Attribute Evaluator (supervised, Class (nominal): 4 class):
    Information Gain Ranking Filter

Ranked attributes:
 0.971  3 attr3
 0.971  2 attr2
 0      1 attr1

Selected attributes: 3,2,1 : 3
```

Now, attribute 3 rightfully has an information gain of 0.971 which equals the entropy of the relation. Evaluating the other two attributes with the information gain does not really make sense as those contain highly mutual information. But what I do not understand, is why one overfitting attribute has the maximum information gain while the other one has the minimum information gain. How does the Information Gain Attribute Evaluator handle those overfitting attributes?